# tabla calificaciones laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

Tengo una tabla y su respectivo modelo Calificación, donde tengo 8 notas, promedio, examen, nota final. En mi controlador calculo el promedio con las notas distintas de 0, y la nota final.

```
function guardarCalificacion(CalificacionRequest $request) {
    $calificacion = new Calificacion($request->all());

    $calificacion->id_profesor = auth('profesor')->user()->id;

    $profesor        = Profesor::find(auth('profesor')->user()->id);
    $mis_asignaturas = $profesor->asignaturas->all();

    $cantidad = 0;

    if (($calificacion->n1) != null) {
        $cantidad = $cantidad + 1;
    } else {
        $calificacion->n1 = 0;
    }

    if ($calificacion->n2 != null) {
        $cantidad = $cantidad + 1;
    } else {
        $calificacion->n2 = 0;
    }

    if ($calificacion->n3 != null) {
        $cantidad = $cantidad + 1;
    } else {
        $calificacion->n3 = 0;
    }

    if ($calificacion->n4 != null) {
        $cantidad = $cantidad + 1;
    } else {
        $calificacion->n4 = 0;
    }

    if ($calificacion->n5 != null) {
        $cantidad = $cantidad + 1;
    } else {
        $calificacion->n5 = 0;
    }

    if ($calificacion->n6 != null) {
        $cantidad = $cantidad + 1;
    } else {
        $calificacion->n6 = 0;
    }

    if ($calificacion->n7 != null) {
        $cantidad = $cantidad + 1;
    } else {
        $calificacion->n7 = 0;
    }

    if ($calificacion->n8 != null) {
        $cantidad = $cantidad + 1;
    } else {
        $calificacion->n8 = 0;
    }

    $calificacion->promedio = ($calificacion->n1 + $calificacion->n2 + $calificacion->n3 + $calificacion->n4 + $calificacion->n5 + $calificacion->n6 + $calificacion->n7 + $calificacion->n8) / $cantidad;

    if ($calificacion->examen != null) {
        $calificacion->final = ($calificacion->promedio + $calificacion->examen) / 2;
    }

    $calificacion->save();

    flash('Calificacion agregada exitosamente!', 'success');
    return view('datos-profesor/asignaturas')->with('calificacion', $calificacion)->with('profesor', $profesor)->with('mis_asignaturas', $mis_asignaturas);
}
```

Lo que quiero es sacar esa variable de promedio y nota final de mi tabla, para que no dependan la una de la otra. que esas dos variables se calculen en el controlador y se muestren en la vista, sin necesidad que de que mi tabla Calificaciones tenga esos dos atributos `($calificacion->promedio , $calificacion->final)`, como  puedo hacer eso y mandarlos a mi vista? tengo la idea de colocar simplemente

```
$promedio = ($calificacion->n1 + $calificacion->n2 + $calificacion->n3 + $calificacion->n4 + $calificacion->n5 + $calificacion->n6 + $calificacion->n7 + $calificacion->n8) / $cantidad;

$final = ($calificacion->promedio + $calificacion->examen) / 2;
```

Pero nose como enviarla a la vista,  esta es mi vista :

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">                           
    <tr>    
        <th>N1</th>
        <th>N2</th>
        <th>N3</th>
        <th>N4</th>
        <th>N5</th>
        <th>N6</th>
        <th>N7</th>
        <th>N8</th>
        <th>Promedio  </th>
        <th>Examen  </th>
        <th>Final  </th>
        <th>Observacion  </th>
        <th>Opciones  </th>
    </tr>                                
    @foreach($mis_notas as $mis_notas)  
    <tr>
        <td>{{$mis_notas->n1}}</td>
        <td>{{$mis_notas->n2}}</td>
        <td>{{$mis_notas->n3}}</td>
        <td>{{$mis_notas->n4}}</td>
        <td>{{$mis_notas->n5}}</td>
        <td>{{$mis_notas->n6}}</td>
        <td>{{$mis_notas->n7}}</td>
        <td>{{$mis_notas->n8}}</td>
        <td>{{$mis_notas->promedio}}</td>
        <td>{{$mis_notas->examen}}</td>
        <td>{{$mis_notas->final}}</td>
        <td>{{$mis_notas->observacion}}</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{URL('modificar/calificacion', array($mis_notas->id_alumno, $mis_notas->id_asignatura, $mis_notas->id ))}}"> Agregar Notas</a></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Como podría hacerlo? para enviar la variable `$promedio` y `$final` a la vista? ya que esta dentro del `for` de mis_notas??

Modelo Calificación

```
protected $table = "calificaciones";

protected $fillable = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6', 'n7', 'n8', 'promedio', 'examen', 'final', 'observacion', 'id_alumno',  'id_asignatura', 'id_profesor'];

public function alumno()
{ 
    return $this->belongsTo(Alumno::class, 'id_alumno', 'id');
}

public function asignatura()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Asignatura::class, 'id_asignatura', 'id');
}

public function profesor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Profesor::class, 'id_profesor', 'id');
}
```

Modelo Alumno

```
protected $table = "alumnos";

protected $fillable = ['rut', 'nombre', 'apellido_paterno', 'apellido_materno', 'email', 'password', 'sexo', 'telefono', 'foto', 'fecha_nacimiento', 'direccion', 'id_curso', 'id_apoderado'];

protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

public function curso()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Curso::class,'id_curso','id');
}

public function apoderado()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Apoderado::class,'id_apoderado','id'); 
}

public function matriculas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Matricula');
}

public function asignaturas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Asignatura');
}

public function conductas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Conducta','id_alumno');
}

public function calificaciones()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Calificacion','id_alumno');
}
```

Modelo Asignatura

```
protected $table = "asignaturas";

protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'horario', 'periodo', 'codigo', 'id_sala', 'id_curso', 'id_profesor'];

public function sala()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Sala::class,'id_sala','id');
}

public function curso()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Curso::class,'id_curso','id');
}

public function profesor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Profesor::class,'id_profesor','id');
}

public function alumnos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Alumno')->withTimestamps();
}

public function conductas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Conducta','id_asignatura');
}

public function eventos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Evento','id_asignatura');
}

public function calificaciones()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Calificacion','id_asignatura');
}
```

El alumno se matricula en un curso y el curso tiene asignaturas

Comment: Si y la tabla calificacion recibe la id de alumnos y la de asignatura

Comment: ok, deje los modelos en la pregunta

Comment: Esto es para enseñanza basica-media en Chile? o para modelo universitario? :P

Comment: SI para enseñanza media de un liceo en Chile

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59427/discussion-between-edgardo-escobar-and-arie-cwhat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el promedio de notas de un alumno, podrías definir una tabla "notas" como la siguiente:

```php
Schema::create('notas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('id_alumno')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('id_evaluacion')->unsigned();
    $table->string('nota', 3, 2); // un entero, dos decimales ... 2.00, 7.00, 4.00

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

luego ingresas datos como estos:

```
id  id_alumno  id_evaluacion  nota
1,  1,         1,             4.60
2,  1,         2,             5.60
3,  1,         3,             4.40
4,  1,         4,             6.50
5,  1,         5,             2.30
6,  1,         6,             4.50
7,  1,         7,             7.00
8,  1,         8,             2.60
9,  2,         1,             4.70
10, 2,         2,             6.70
11, 2,         3,             4.30
12, 2,         4,             1.20
13, 2,         5,             4.60
14, 2,         6,             7.00
15, 2,         7,             5.60
```

Y para sacar el promedio usas una Query como esta:

```sql
SELECT sum(nota)/count(*) as Promedio FROM notas WHERE id_alumno = 1 GROUP BY id_alumno;
```

(en Laravel sería como esto, pero no lo he provado :P )

```php
DB::table('notas')
    ->select('sum(nota)/count(*)')
    ->where('id_alumno', 1)
    ->groupBy('id_alumno')
    ->get();
```

Donde el resultado es:

```
Promedio
4.687500
```